# releasing resources when the other thread goes into an infinite loop after blocking a shared resource

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

In the code below, although I avoid deadlock( due to reverse locking hierarchy). However, due to T2 going into an infinite loop, the mutex m1 and m2 never get released, in this case the system can neither achieve progress nor bounded wait( in terms of time). How can I handle this kind of scenario ? Is there a way to interrupt the thread that is holding the resource? At least with pthread mutexes the ownership of the mutex is with the thread that locked it! How could we unlock the mutex held by the other thread ?

Thread T1 :

```
 while(1) {
  pthread_mutex_lock( &m1);
    //use resource 1
    if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&m2) ) {
       //Got the lock, do processing
      }
    else {
       //Release m1
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        continue;
     }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
    }

Thread T2:

       pthread_mutex_lock( &m2);
       pthread_mutex_lock(&m1)
       //Goes in an infinite loop here
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);
     }
```

Comment: Don't go into an infinite loop while holding a mutex?

Comment: A thread cannot unlock a mutex acquired by another thread. If you want to do that, you should use a binary semaphore (because semaphores support raw wait / post operations which are not thread-dependent).